# docker web container not finding the database from mysql container

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker and docker-compose for the local development host as we're working in a team of frontend developers and backend developer, using django as the backend with mysql as the sgbd, so the project was running well in docker( only the backend is dockerized), after the last commit everything crashed , so i'm getting the following logs from the web container:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
2023-04-25 23:13:25     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
2023-04-25 23:13:25     fn(*args, **kwargs)
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
2023-04-25 23:13:25     self.check_migrations()
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check_migrations
2023-04-25 23:13:25     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
2023-04-25 23:13:25     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
2023-04-25 23:13:25     self.build_graph()
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
2023-04-25 23:13:25     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
2023-04-25 23:13:25     if self.has_table():
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
2023-04-25 23:13:25     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
2023-04-25 23:13:25     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
2023-04-25 23:13:25     return self._cursor()
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
2023-04-25 23:13:25     self.ensure_connection()
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
2023-04-25 23:13:25     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 218, in ensure_connection
2023-04-25 23:13:25     with self.wrap_database_errors:
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
2023-04-25 23:13:25     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
2023-04-25 23:13:25     self.connect()
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
2023-04-25 23:13:25     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
2023-04-25 23:13:25     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
2023-04-25 23:13:25     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
2023-04-25 23:13:25     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
2023-04-25 23:13:25     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
2023-04-25 23:13:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
2023-04-25 23:13:25     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
2023-04-25 23:13:25 django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'backend'")
```

and from the mysql container :

```
2023-04-25 23:14:01 2023-04-25 22:14:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
2023-04-25 23:14:02 2023-04-25 22:14:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-04-25 23:14:02 2023-04-25 22:14:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
2023-04-25 23:14:02 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2023-04-25 23:14:02 2023-04-25T22:14:02.551101Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-04-25 23:14:02 2023-04-25T22:14:02.552279Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 1
2023-04-25 23:14:02 2023-04-25T22:14:02.561407Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-04-25 23:14:02 2023-04-25T22:14:02.820157Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-04-25 23:14:03 2023-04-25T22:14:03.166991Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-04-25 23:14:03 2023-04-25T22:14:03.167059Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-04-25 23:14:03 2023-04-25T22:14:03.171995Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2023-04-25 23:14:03 2023-04-25T22:14:03.200166Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-04-25 23:14:03 2023-04-25T22:14:03.200281Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

this is my DockerFile :

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app

# Required to install mysqlclient with Pip
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev gcc -y

# Install pipenv
RUN pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip install pipenv

# Install application dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /app/
# We use the --system flag so packages are installed into the system python
# and not into a virtualenv. Docker containers don't need virtual environments. 
RUN pipenv install --system --dev

# Copy the application files into the image
COPY . /app/

# Expose port 8000 on the container
EXPOSE 8000
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3.10'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - 3366:3306
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=backend
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql 
  web:
    build: .
    command: ./wait-for-it.sh mysql:3366 -- ./docker-entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/app
volumes:
  mysqldata:
```

docker-entrypoint.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Apply database migrations
echo "Apply database migrations"
python manage.py migrate

# Start server
echo "Starting server"
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and my database setting in the settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'backend',
        'HOST' : 'mysql',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'password'
    }
}
```

I've tried using different port for mysql but with no use i still get the same problem.
I've tried running the mysql container first the web container and i still get the same problem.

i've removed the port as the person in the comment said and i'm getting this error now :

````
Attaching to backend-mysql-1, backend-web-1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
backend-mysql-1  | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:34.299213Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:34.300529Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:34.310122Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:34.403303Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.28, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:34.403375Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:34.858931Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:34.859188Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:34.859238Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:34.859635Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
backend-web-1    | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for mysql:33060
backend-mysql-1 exited with code 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
backend-mysql-1  | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:37.270477Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:37.271779Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:37.282664Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:37.398932Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.28, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:37.398980Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:37.852112Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:37.852424Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:37.852484Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:37.853164Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
backend-mysql-1 exited with code 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
backend-mysql-1  | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:40.098484Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:40.099608Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:40.108801Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:40.182449Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.28, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:40.182501Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:40.630781Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:40.631053Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:40.631098Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:40.631530Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
backend-mysql-1 exited with code 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
backend-mysql-1  | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:42.880825Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:42.882112Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:42.891656Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:42.958070Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.28, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:42.958118Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:43.413599Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:43.413822Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:43.413865Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:43.414232Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
backend-mysql-1 exited with code 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
backend-mysql-1  | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:45.962477Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:45.963762Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:45.972911Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:46.039197Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.28, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:46.039250Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:46.494150Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:46.494430Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:46.494476Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:46.494928Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
backend-mysql-1 exited with code 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
backend-mysql-1  | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:49.896883Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:49.897853Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:49.905255Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
backend-web-1    | wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for mysql:33060
backend-web-1    | Apply database migrations
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:49.970895Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.28, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:49.970968Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:50.423683Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:50.423909Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:50.423962Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:50.424523Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
backend-mysql-1 exited with code 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26 08:27:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
backend-mysql-1  | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:55.434680Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:55.435850Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 1
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:55.482289Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:55.558875Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.28, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
backend-mysql-1  | 2023-04-26T08:27:55.558932Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
backend-web-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
backend-web-1    |     self.connect()
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
backend-web-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
backend-web-1    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
backend-web-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
backend-web-1    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
backend-web-1    |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
backend-web-1    |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
backend-web-1    | MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (115)")
backend-web-1    | 
backend-web-1    | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
backend-web-1    | 
backend-web-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend-web-1    |   File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
backend-web-1    |     main()
backend-web-1    |   File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
backend-web-1    |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
backend-web-1    |     utility.execute()
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
backend-web-1    |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
backend-web-1    |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
backend-web-1    |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
backend-web-1    |     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
backend-web-1    |     self.check(databases=[database])
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
backend-web-1    |     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
backend-web-1    |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 13, in check_database_backends
backend-web-1    |     issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
backend-web-1    |     issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
backend-web-1    |     if not (self.connection.sql_mode & {'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'}):
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
backend-web-1    |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 405, in sql_mode
backend-web-1    |     sql_mode = self.mysql_server_data['sql_mode']
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
backend-web-1    |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 366, in mysql_server_data
backend-web-1    |     with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
backend-web-1    |     return next(self.gen)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
backend-web-1    |     with self.cursor() as cursor:
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
backend-web-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
backend-web-1    |     return self._cursor()
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
backend-web-1    |     self.ensure_connection()
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
backend-web-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 218, in ensure_connection
backend-web-1    |     with self.wrap_database_errors:
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
backend-web-1    |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
backend-web-1    |     self.connect()
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
backend-web-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
backend-web-1    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
backend-web-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
backend-web-1    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
backend-web-1    |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
backend-web-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
backend-web-1    |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
backend-web-1    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (115)")
backend-web-1    | Starting server```
````

Comment: Run `docker exec -ti mysql bash` from the docker host while the `mysql` service is running, and inside the container check if the `backend` database exists from the mysql cli.

Comment: Remove `ports: - 3366:3306` from the docker-compose file if you don't need to access from outside and add `'PORT' : 33060,` to your settings.py file. Change also the port in your `web:command` accordingly.

Comment: this approach showed the latest above errors.

Comment: Your database seems corrupted. Read these recovery instructions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP abandoned it